# Oracl SQL: update a column with same column's value in other rows with condition on other columns

Tags: oracle, sql-update, inner-join

I want to update a column (if NULL) with value of same column from a row which has same value in another column (assuming that such row exists and it is unique). In the example below, Order_ID=2 has NULL Group_ID. The query should insert Group_ID of a (unique) row which has the same value in Quantity column. (This is a simplified example. The real table has 30 columns and 900'000 rows).

```
Order_ID  Price  Quantity  Group_ID
1         10     15        345
2         21     15        NULL
```

So the expected output is:

```
Order_ID  Price  Quantity  Group_ID
1         10     15        345
2         21     15        345
```

I tried this query, but it obviously gets stuck and I have to stop it (after hours):

```
update My_Table t1
set Group_ID=(select t2.Group_ID 
from My_Table t1 inner join My_Table t2
on
t1.Quantity = t2.Quantity
where t1.Group_ID is not NULL and t2.Group_ID is NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the group_id to a group_id value from the first record with the same quantity that is selected.

```
update table t1
set group_id = (select group_id from table t2
                where t1.quantity=t2.quantity
                and t2.group_id is not null
                and rownum=1)
where group_id is null
```

Comment: I ran your query. Again it is taking too much time. Given the size of the table, should it take hours?

Comment: Maybe you need an index on the quantity column. See here how to create an explain plan which will give you more information on where how the query is executed: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18639/how-do-you-get-the-explain-plan

Comment: Now I have the plan_table. For UPDATE STATEMENT, CPU_cost is 221447373180674, IO_cost: 2894221652, time: 34859082. I have to confess that I am not sure that I understand these numbers, but have a feeling that they are too big. How can I make the query efficient?

Comment: Really big numbers. Can you add an index on quantity? See what that does to the numbers.

Comment: Sorry for being such a beginner, but how can I "add an index" to a column?

Comment: I tried this: `CREATE INDEX Q_IND ON My_Table (Quantity)` but got "resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified".

Comment: Some process is updating the table. Rollback or commit that transaction.